# error creating an email (from gmail to gmail) with mime::lite perl

Tags: perl, gmail

i created this code(to send an email from gmail to gmail):

```
   use MIME::Lite;
   use Net::SMTP::SSL;
 my $smtps = Net::SMTP::SSL->new ("www.gmail.com", Port=> 465);
  $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
             From     =>'testeotest1234@gmail.com',
             To       =>'xxx',
     #        Cc       =>'some@other.com, some@more.com',
             Encoding => 'base64',
             Subject  =>'Helloooooo, nurse!',
             Data     =>"How's it goin', eh?"
             );

  MIME::Lite->send('smtp','smtp.gmail.com', Port=> 465, Debug=>1, Hello =>'www.gmail.com',AuthUser=>'testeotest1234', AuthPass=>'xxx');

$msg->send();
```

but i get this error:

```
Port=> 465MIME::Lite::SMTP>>> MIME::Lite::SMTP
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>   Net::SMTP(2.31)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>     Net::Cmd(2.29)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>       Exporter(5.65)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>     IO::Socket::INET(1.31)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>       IO::Socket(1.32)
MIME::Lite::SMTP>>>         IO::Handle(1.31)
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP kn18sm4777324veb.5 -
 gsmtp
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)>>> EHLO www.gmail.com
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [12.226.1
28.130]
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 250-SIZE 35882577
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 250-8BITMIME
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 250-STARTTLS
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0x244c0d4)<<< 250 PIPELINING
SMTP auth() command not supported on smtp.gmail.com
```

i tried using mail::sender:easy (cant install it, gives me an error when i try), i try to use the SSL line to create a conection before (due to how gmail conection works, but to no avail

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "SMTP Failed to connect to mail server:" when I try to send an email to a Gmail account using MIME::Lite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635906/why-do-i-get-smtp-failed-to-connect-to-mail-server-when-i-try-to-send-an-emai)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`Email::Sender`](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSender) with [`Email::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/Email%3a%3aSimple). They are relatively new modules, and much nicer than most others.

Comment: i tried email::sender but i get an error in the instalation (im using padre). but i fixed the issue i used Email::Send::SMTP::Gmail, and that did the trick