# Why do I get "SMTP Failed to connect to mail server:" when I try to send an email to a Gmail account using MIME::Lite?

Tags: perl, email, authentication, smtp

I have following code to send an email in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Lite;

$to = 'toid@domain.com';
$cc = 'ccid@domain.com';
$from = 'fromid@domain.com';

$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
             From     => $from,
             To       => $to,
             Cc       => $cc,
             Subject  => $subject,
             Data     => $message
             );

$msg->send;
#$msg->send('smtp', "smtp.gmail.com", AuthUser=>"myid@domain.com", AuthPass=>"mypass" );
#$msg->send('smtp', "smtp.gmail.com",  Debug=>0 );
#$msg->send('type',@args);
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
SMTP Failed to connect to mail server:
```

When I call `$msg->send` with arguments (see the commented lines above) I get the following error:

```
SMTP auth() command not supported on smtp.gmail.com
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try connecting to your own ISP's or workplace's SMTP server rather than Google's?

Answer (score 2):

Somebody filed a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=70216) for this several years ago. The maintainer's response was:

> This is unlikely to be fixed.
>
> MIME::Lite does not support Net::SMTP::TLS, and I don't see myself implementing that in the future. I strongly suggest moving off of MIME::Lite to tools like Email::Sender and Email::MIME or other more-supported tools.

Note that you shouldn't even be using `MIME::Lite` in the first place, since the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT) recommends against it:

> ## WAIT!
>
> MIME::Lite is not recommended by its current maintainer. There are a number of alternatives, like Email::MIME or MIME::Entity and Email::Sender, which you should probably use instead. MIME::Lite continues to accrue weird bug reports, and it is not receiving a large amount of refactoring due to the availability of better alternatives. Please consider using something else.

Comment: I haven't written any code that sent email in a while, but MIME::Lite was my module of choice for it...

Answer (score 2):

MIME::Lite is (as ThisSuitIsNotBlack notes) deprecated.

This works for me, using the preferred Email::Sender:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver = 'server';
my $smtpport = 587;
my $smtpuser   = 'username';
my $smtppassword = 'password';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
  host => $smtpserver,
  port => $smtpport,
  ssl => "starttls",
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'mymail@gmail.com',
    From    => 'sender@example.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "This is my message\n",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed with Net::SMTP 3.05 (the latest version at CPAN).  It supports SMTPS and STARTTLS.
[ **WARNING:** see [MIME::Lite 3.030 - NET::SMTP with smtps (port 465)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588971/mimelite-3-030-netsmtp-with-smtps-port-465) ]

```
# It should work with Net::SMTP 3.05
# MIME::Lite will pass SSL=>1 to Net::SMTP constructor
$msg->send('smtp', "smtp.gmail.com", SSL=>1,
AuthUser=>"myid@domain.com", AuthPass=>"mypass" );
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, and reading the code for MIME::Lite 3.030 (current latest) I can't see how it could work; MIME::Lite simply never calls SMTP->starttls().

Comment: According to Net::SMTP 3.* documentation it should make Net::SMTP use smtps (port 465 with instant SSL negotiation) instead of standard port 25.

Answer (score 0):

The above worked when

1. I used my Gmail as the SMTP --> Bet you didn't think you could do that.

```
my $smtpserver  = 'smtp.gmail.com.';
my $smtpport     = 587;
my $smtpuser     = 'YourGmailHere@gmail.com';
my $smtppassword = 'password'; ## Plug in your password here
```

2. Then you have to actually set your security for your Gmail account to a less secure … basically set "Less secure app access" to "ON" 
   setting --> https://myaccount.google.com/security

Hope this helps others.