# SMTP auth() command not supported on smtp.office365.com

Tags: perl, email, office365

```
use warnings;
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

### Adjust sender, recipient and your SMTP mailhost
my $from_address = 'doni@home.com';
my $to_address = 'doni@home.com';
my $mail_host = 'smtp.office365.com';

### Adjust subject and body message
my $subject = 'A message with 2 parts ...';
my $message_body = "Here's the attachment file(s) you wanted";

### Adjust the filenames
my $my_file_txt = 'C:\Users\Doni\Documents';
my $your_file_txt = 'test1.txt';

### Create the multipart container
$msg = MIME::Lite->new (
    From => $from_address,
    To => $to_address,
    Subject => $subject,
    Type =>'multipart/mixed'
) or die "Error creating multipart container: $!\n";

### Add the text message part
$msg->attach (
    Type => 'TEXT',
    Data => $message_body
) or die "Error adding the text message part: $!\n";

### Add the TEXT file
$msg->attach (
    Type => 'text',
    Encoding => 'base64',
    Path => $my_file_txt,
    Filename => $your_file_txt,
    Disposition => 'attachment'
) or die "Error adding file_text: $!\n";

##Send 
MIME::Lite->send('smtp',$mail_host,SSL=>0,AuthUser=>'doni@home.com',AuthPass=>'******',Debug=>1,Port=>587,Timeout=>60);
$msg->send;
```

the output of the command is:

```
##Here's the output

SMTP auth() command not supported on smtp.office365.com
```

How to resolve that issue? I'm stuck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above all, I added

```
use Net::SMTP::TLS;
```

after MIME::Lite codes, I used below mailer:

```
my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
    "smtp.office365.com",
    Hello   =>      'smtp.office365.com',
    Port    =>      587,
    User    =>      'doni@home.com',
    Password=>      '******');
$mailer->mail('doni@home.com');
$mailer->to('doni@home.com');
$mailer->data;
$mailer->datasend($msg->as_string);
$mailer->dataend;
$mailer->quit;
```

It worked like a charm!

Comment: You might instead also use the Net::SMTP (core module) and just do a `$mailer->starttls()` after establishing the connection. One less module to install. Also, you could simply do `$mailer->data($msg->as_string)` and skip the `datesend` and `dataend`.

Comment: two thumbs up for you bro @SteffenUllrich

Answer (score 1):

```
MIME::Lite->send('smtp',$mail_host,SSL=>0,AuthUser=>...,Port=>587 ...
                                   ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^
```

You are trying to use authentication without SSL. This is not supported by smtp.office365.com for security reasons as can be seen in the handshake. The response to EHLO after the initial connect shows no AUTH available:

```
<<< 220 LNXP265CA0010.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 16 Oct 2017 14:36:53 +0000
>>> EHLO ...
<<< 250-LNXP265CA0010.outlook.office365.com Hello ...
<<< 250-SIZE 157286400
<<< 250-PIPELINING
<<< 250-DSN
<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<<< 250-STARTTLS
<<< 250-8BITMIME
<<< 250-BINARYMIME
<<< 250-CHUNKING
<<< 250 SMTPUTF8
```

Only when upgrading to TLS AUTH gets available:

```
>>> STARTTLS
<<< 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
>>> EHLO localhost.localdomain
<<< 250-LNXP265CA0010.outlook.office365.com Hello ...
<<< 250-SIZE 157286400
<<< 250-PIPELINING
<<< 250-DSN
<<< 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<<< 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2          <<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
<<< 250-8BITMIME
<<< 250-BINARYMIME
<<< 250-CHUNKING
<<< 250 SMTPUTF8
```

Unfortunately, it looks like MIME::Lite does not support the use of starttls. See the anwers on [MIME::Lite - Cannot send mail [SMTP auth() command not supported on smtp.gmail.com]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337178/mimelite-cannot-send-mail-smtp-auth-command-not-supported-on-smtp-gmail-c) for alternatives.

Comment: I already followed and edited my code to add SSL=>1 and use NET::SMTP(3.10) but still didn't work. What is the best way to send email to office365 then?

Comment: @DoniAndriCahyono: `SSL => 1` does not use explicit TLS (i.e. starttls) but implicit TLS. To cite myself: *"Unfortunately, it looks like MIME::Lite does not support the use of starttls. See the anwers on MIME::Lite - Cannot send mail .... for alternatives*".

Comment: `MIME::Lite` does not pass `SSL` option to `Net::SMTP` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588971/mimelite-3-030-netsmtp-with-smtps-port-465

Comment: @AnFi: and that's on top of `SSL => 1` not being the right option anyway :)

Comment: It looks like good fix for services supporting smtps (port 465, e.g. gmail) **BUT** MIME::Lite filters it out from options passed to `Net::SMTP` constructor (`new`).

Comment: Thanks fellas, it brought me an idea to seek net::smtp with TLS and put it as my answer

Answer (score 0):

For me the above solution, using `Net::SMTP::TLS`, did not work for sending emails using `MIME::Lite` & Office365. I received the following error message:

```
invalid SSL_version specified at /usr/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm line 575.
```

However, the solution given [here](http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/send-email-using-perl-via-live.com.html) using `Net::SMTPS`, worked like a charm.

Here's the code snippet that worked for me:

```
my $email = MIME::Lite->new(From    => 'John Doe <john.doe@example.com>',
                             To      => $to,
                             Subject => $email_subject,
                             Type    =>'multipart/related' );

$email->attach(Type => 'text/html',
               Data => $email_body);

my $smtps = Net::SMTPS->new("smtp.office365.com", Port => 587,  doSSL => 'starttls', SSL_version=>'TLSv1');

my $username = 'john.doe@example.com';
my $password = 'myc0mpl1c4t3dpa55w0rd';

$smtps->auth ( $username, $password ) or DIE("Nooooo..Could not authenticate with mail server!!\n");

$smtps->mail($username);
$smtps->to($to);
$smtps->data();
$smtps->datasend( $email->as_string() );
$smtps->dataend();
$smtps->quit;
```

Hope this helps someone.