# Perl Email function Mime::Lite

Tags: perl, email, smtp

Im fairly new to Perl programming. I need help on the basic SMTP using MIME::Lite, I have already downloaded the library and put it on the folder.
Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTP;

$to = 'sample@gmail.com';
$cc = 'sample@gmail.com';
$from = 'sample@gmail.com';
$pass = "my password here";
$subject = 'Test Email';
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script';

$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
                 From     => $from,
                 To       => $to,
                 Cc       => $cc,
                 Subject  => $subject,
                 Data     => $message
                 );

# MIME::Lite->send('smtp', "smtp.gmail.com");
MIME::Lite->send('smtp', "smtp.gmail.com", Timeout=>60,Auth=>'LOGIN',AuthUser=>$from,AuthPass=>$pass,Port => 465, Debug => 1);
$msg->send;
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

I'm getting an error of:

```
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> MIME::LITE::SMTP
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> NET::SMTP(3.10)
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> NET::CMD(3.10)
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> EXPORTER(5.72)
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> IO::SOCKET::IP(0.39)
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> IO::SOCKET(1.38)
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> IO::HANDLE(1.36)
MIME::LITE::SMTP>>> NET::CMD::GETLINE(): UNEXPECTED EOF ON COMMAND CHANNEL: AT C:/STRAWBERRY/PERL/LIBE/MIME/LITE.PM LINE 2622 AT MAIN.PL LINE 23
SMTP FAILED TO CONNECT TO MAIL SERVER: BAD FILE DESCRIPTOR AT LINE 23
```

Am I missing something here? I saw the tutorial and it is working for them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635906/why-do-i-get-smtp-failed-to-connect-to-mail-server-when-i-try-to-send-an-emai

Comment: I will never understand why people use modules that [even the current maintainer](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#WAIT!) advise against using.

Comment: @DaveCross  Perhaps unaware of it?  They seem to be working from an outdated tutorial.

Comment: @zdim: Sure. But step one when looking into an issue like this is surely "read the documentation for the module" and step two is "see if there's a more recent version of the module". So there's no excuse for not being aware of it.

Comment: @DaveCross  Absolutely agree (didn't mean to hint at an excuse).  But people so often don't, unfortunately.. I've just recently advised an OP to read docs, probably three times in a long exchange ... only to see their new question the next day, on the same module and still clearly completely uninformed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45588971/2139766

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone's advice. So Since Mime::lite not that good I changed my approach to Net::SMTP. Here is my code below for future reference.

Also note that I was not able to make it work for google but our own smtp server work fine for the code.

```
#!perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::SMTP;

my $smtpserver = 'mail server';
my $smtpport = 'port' ;
my $smtpuser   = 'sender@sample.com';
my $smtppassword = 'my password';


my $smtp = Net::SMTP->new($smtpserver, Port=>$smtpport, Timeout => 60, Debug => 1);
die "Could not connect to server!\n" unless $smtp; 

$smtp->auth($smtpuser, $smtppassword);
$smtp->mail('sender@sample.com');
$smtp->to('receiver@sample.com');

$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("To: receiver name <receiver\@sample.com>\n");
$smtp->datasend("From: sender name <sender\@sample.com>\n");
$smtp->datasend("subject: THIS IS A SUBJECT\n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");
$smtp->datasend("A simple test message\n");

$smtp->quit;
```

Comment: I was wondering why you reached for `MIME::Lite`, and not knowing it thought that there may be a reason.  So I restrained from commenting -- I use this and have had no problem.

Comment: I'm really new to perl and while looking for a way MIME::Lite has the most sample. Though I tried Email::Simple, and Net::SMTP and was not really working. So I went back to MIME::Lite. After I ran out of ideas I posted the question.

Then I went back to Net::SMTP and tried again then it worked. I tried as much as possible to not use Mime.

Comment: Add `SSL=>1` to `Net::SMTP->new(...)` options.

Comment: SSL=>1 is not working (but from what i know it supposed to work since if I use it on php it supposed to be SSL => 1 to go out of your network) so I tried SSL=> 0 now it works if the recipient is outside my network.